# Why is 5-chloro-1-methylcyclopentene not named 3-chloro-2-methylcyclopentene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Why is the ring numbered the way it is? What is it about the double bond that makes it so?

[image: molecule]

[source](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.60606630.html?rid=8f17c9ed-c57d-48db-9f7f-fce5829be7c2)

Answer (score 0):

Acoording to the IUPAC rules for nomenclature of the *halo* compounds the $\ce{Cl}$ here is treated like $\ce{CH3}$. And also according to rule, the double bond have preference over the groups other than *functional* groups.

Comment: Note that you can significantly improve your answer by quoting the exact IUPAC rule you are referring to, e.g. see how it's done in [one of the answers on related topic](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/32589/41328).